# C# retrieve data from Bored API

Tags: c#

I'm trying to retrieve data from https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity, a public API, with the following code in C#:

```
namespace TesteAval
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<Activity> ActList;
        private Activity Act;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            LoadActivities();
        }

        private async void LoadActivities() 
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.boredapi.com/");

            var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/activity");
            //var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/activity?key=5881028");

            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(response.ReasonPhrase);
                return;
            }

            ActList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Activity>>(result);
            Act = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Activity>(result);

            listBoxDashBoard.DataSource = ActList;
            listBoxDashBoard.DisplayMember = "TypeActivitySimple";
        }
    }
}
```

Already made the conversion via postman (retrieved the json) and converted to C" (via json2c#). My goal is to create a List ActList with 10 objects but get an error. Also tried to retrieve just one object to var Act but got another error.
I tested this exact same code (with different class from json2c#) with another API http://cambios.somee.com/api/Rates and it works.

Also already have the class (from json2C# converter):

```
namespace TesteAval
{
    public class Activity
    {
        public string activity { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public int participants { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
        public string key { get; set; }
        public double accessibility { get; set; }

        public string TypeActivitySimple
        {
            get
            {
                return $"{activity} - {type} ";
            }
        }

        public string TypeActivity 
        {
            get 
            {
                return $"{activity} - {type} - {participants} - {price} - {link} - {key} - {accessibility}";
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You appear to be trying to convert the result string into a List of Activity and then the exact same string into a single Activity. Because you haven’t stated what the actual error is then I presume that one of these will be the cause of your issue. If this is incorrect, please post the actual error you’re getting g

Comment: @scottdavidwalker right you are, my bad in forgetting to post the error. Found the way to work though. Since the Bored API does not return a List of objects, rather returns one, took me some time to realize that I was already fetching one Object (That I was saving on the var Act.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I sorted this problem out. I don't know if I'm required to post the solution. If so (if he admins wish so) I'll gladly do it. I can't answer my onw question, I don't have permission to do so (account rank).

Comment: It's not a requirement to post your own solution, but if it's helpful to someone else then it is worthwhile to do so. Leave another comment if you can't post your own answers yet :-).

Comment: @scottdavidwalker it's really hard to post all I wanted in a comment (due to constraint of string size). Here's the code:

Comment: `private async void LoadActivities()
        {
             for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.boredapi.com/");
                var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/activity");
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

Comment: `if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(response.ReasonPhrase);
                    return;
                }
                Act = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Activity>(result);
                ActList.Add(Act);
            }
            label1.Text = Act.ToString();
            listBoxDashBoard.DataSource = ActList;
            listBoxDashBoard.DisplayMember = "TypeActivitySimple";
        }`

Comment: @scottdavidwalker since you have the reputation for it, would you mind to grab my code and post it as an answer plz? ty